# getElementById Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a Pythagoras calculator, I have 3 input boxes, and you fill 2 in, press a button and it will fill the final one in with the answer, here's my code.

HTML:

```
<div id="theorem">
    <h2>Calculator</h2>
    <input id="a" placeholder="a"/>
    <input id="b" placeholder="b"/>
    <input id="c" placeholder="c"/>
    <button onclick="workOut()">Work out</button>
</div>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

JavaScript:

```
function workOut() {
    var a = document.getElementById(a).value;
    var b = document.getElementById(b).value;
    var c = document.getElementById(c).value;

    if (a == "") {
        A(b, c);
    }
    if (b == "") {
        B(c, a);
    }
    if (c == "") {
        C(a, b);
    }
}

function A(sideB, sideC){
    a.innerHTML = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(sideC, 2) - Math.pow(sideB, 2));
}
function B(sideA, sideC){
    b.innerHTML = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(sideC, 2) - Math.pow(sideA, 2));
}
function C(sideA, sideB){
    c.innerHTML = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(sideA, 2) + Math.pow(sideB, 2));
}
```

Each time I run I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at workOut
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

Comment: `getElementById('a')` rather than `getElementById(a)`. `a` is something you assign to. `'a'` is a literal id of the element.

Comment: You should also parse the strings to float or integer: `a = parseFloat(a)`

Comment: Also inside the `A`, `B` and `C` methods, it should be `a.value` instead of `a.innerHTML`

Comment: @WiktorZychla please vote to close as typo

Comment: @adiga I do agree this is just a typo on my end, thanks for the help though, is there a way I can close this now (also new to stack overflow)

Comment: These are usually closed and [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) automatically deletes them after 30 days since they have no future value. You can click on the delete button below the question.

Comment: (You can't delete a question with accepted or upvoted answer BTW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but don't you have to write document.getElementById("a").value instead of (a)?